# BSODs related to ntoskrnl after fresh install of Windows 11

Tags: windows, drivers, bsod

Yesterday I did a fresh install of Windows 11 and began to get bluescreens in the form of `IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL`, `SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED`, and `KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED`, they're all related to `ntoskrnl`. I have run Windows Memory Diagnostic as well as Memtest86 for three passes and both tests reported no issues so I am beginning to suspect it's a fault with one of my drivers. I have run CHKDISK as well as DXDiag with no issues reported, I have also run WhoCrashed, and all it tells me is that it is likely an issue with one of my drivers.

I will perhaps try uninstalling all of them and installing what I need most one by one until I experience issues, I also plan on downgrading to Windows 10. Thank you, here are my [dump files](https://www.mediafire.com/file/g78poia0k2g99wu/123023-9765-01.zip/file).

Comment: That is typically a driver issue. Is there a manufacturer's driver update App for your computer. If so, update with that

Comment: Instead of providing the memory dump, can you provide the WinDBG analysis, which is more helpful than the memory dump itself. Windows 10 will be supported until 2025. It’s a perfectly fine and secure operating system. There is absolutely no reason to upgrade to Windows 11 at this time. I can almost guarantee you that you would have this same issue with Windows 11 by the way.